# Adding points progress bar to drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to add a progress bar to my app: it fullness will be updated from the application and it will be shown in the navigator drawer. I don't know how to represent the bar icon (filled partly rectangle).
Any ideas?

[image: Bar in drawer]

Answer (score 0):

As indicated at the [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) you can just change the style of the `ProgressBar` class to get the result you would like.  All from within the standard Drawer layout.

```
<ProgressBar
 style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
 ... />
```